# Flutter Difference between InitState and just putting inside Widget Build function

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I had an error every time I restarted my App: `This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).` and saw that something was not correct with my initstate. The initState was:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      BlocProvider.of<TutSkippedCubit>(context).load();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

the methods loads the data from sharedprefs if I have already skipped the tut or not. Now I solved this issue with removing the initState method and putting the function call inside the widget build:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    BlocProvider.of<TutSkippedCubit>(context).load();
     ....
```

The widget build gets called when the pages loads, so, isn't it the same as the initial state? For what exactly is the methode initState() and I have the feeling that my way of handling this problem is a bad practise, but what would be a better way, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `initState()` method is to control what happens after the app is built. The problem is that you call `BlocProvider` before the app begins. The correct way is to put all the actions after `super.initState()` call and add the context to the `BlocProvider` inside `build` method. Like this:

```
TutSkippedCubit? tutSkippedCubitProvider;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      tutSkippedCubitProvider!.load();
    });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    tutSkippedCubitProvider = BlocProvider.of<TutSkippedCubit>(context);
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I do it like you say the error appears: A value of type 'TutSkippedCubit' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>?'.

Comment: ah okay this worked out. Interesting, good to know thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `initState` and `build` method is called when the widget is inserted into the widget tree, but the `build` method also is called every time the state is changed.

You do need to have in mind that every time the state is changed your method `BlocProvider.of<TutSkippedCubit>(context).load();` also is called.

Maybe, the code below can help you:

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.endOfFrame.then(
      (_) async {
        if (mounted) {
          BlocProvider.of<TutSkippedCubit>(context).load();
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be surprise of getting that error since you are using `BlocProvider.<T>(context)` out of a BuildContext. This context in bracket is the just the same as the one given in the build function.

> The initState() is a method that is called when an object for your
> stateful widget is created and inserted inside the widget tree.